# Ajax calls in Magento Admin Custom module

Tags: angularjs, magento2

I successfully created a custom admin module and loaded successfully in the menu and rendered phtml file successfully.

Then i tried to load some dummy data via ajax using angularJS in same admin module when clicking a button, but the ajax call returns the html content of dashboard of magento admin.

I followed this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-make-a-simple-ajax-call-in-magento-2-1-0)

Following is the code for controller

```
<?php

    namespace DVendor\DemoModule\Controller\Adminhtml\DemoPart;

    use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;


    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
        */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

        protected $jsonPageFactory;


        public function __construct(Context $context,PageFactory $resultPageFactory,JsonFactory $jsonPageFactory){
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->jsonPageFactory = $jsonPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }


        public function execute()
        {
            if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
                $result = $this->jsonPageFactory->create();
                $test=array(
                    'Firstname' => 'What is your firstname',
                    'Email' => 'What is your emailId',
                    'Lastname' => 'What is your lastname',
                    'Country' => 'Your Country'
                );
                return $result->setData($test);
            }
            else{
                return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Following is the JS Code used in phtml file

```
$http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('demomodule/demopart'); ?>',
            //data:$.param({'limit':$scope.definedlimits.value}),
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
        },function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });
```

Comment: admin panel has a "form_key" check, you need to supply it.

Comment: @SlayerBirden when i generate URL with $this->getUrl it provides some key in generated URL, thought that was the key. can you suggest an example?